# How to tell if an object has been released

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, uitableview

How can I tell if an object has been released?

If the UITableViewCell has been moved out screen, kkcell object will be autoreleased by UITableView.

When the audioPlayer finishes, program calls " [kkcell stopSpeakAmination]", but this causes the program to crash.

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag{

    [kkcell stopSpeakAmination];
    playing=NO;
}
```

I also use

```
if(kkcell)
```

or

```
if(kkcell!=nil)
```

but it still crashes.

Here is some more code that I am using:

```
//KKMessageCell2.m
....
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *SenderVoiceNodePlaying;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *ReceiverVoiceNodePlaying;
....

-(void)stopSpeakAmination{
    [self.SenderVoiceNodePlaying stopAnimating];
    [self.ReceiverVoiceNodePlaying stopAnimating];
}

-(void)speakAminationOnRight:(UIButton*)btn{

    //rightside
    NSArray *speekImageAry = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"SenderVoiceNodePlaying001"],
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"SenderVoiceNodePlaying002"],
                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"SenderVoiceNodePlaying003"], nil];


    self.SenderVoiceNodePlaying.animationImages = speekImageAry; 
    self.SenderVoiceNodePlaying.animationDuration = 1.0; 
    self.SenderVoiceNodePlaying.animationRepeatCount = 0; 
    [self.SenderVoiceNodePlaying startAnimating];

    NSString *fileName=btn.titleLabel.text;
    fileName=[fileName substringFromIndex:10];
    KKMessageCell2 *cell=(KKMessageCell2*)[btn superview];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"nPlayAmr"
                                    object:nil userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                         fileName,@"fileName",
                                                         cell,@"cell",nil]];
}

//KKMessageCell2.m
....

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"msgCell";
    NSDictionary *dict = [messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    KKMessageCell2 *cell = [[[KKMessageCell2 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    [cell setCellView:dict andMy_avatar_url:self.my_avatar_url];
    [cell.avatarLeftImageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pushToUserDetail:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.avatarRightImageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pushToUserDetail:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.chatphoto addTarget:self action:@selector(photoClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    return cell;

}

- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag{

    [kkcell stopSpeakAmination];
    playing=NO;
}
```

Comment: The first thing to ask is, are you using ARC?

Comment: A table view cell is not released when it scrolls off screen, it's put into the reuse queue. You really need to post more code, it's hard to tell what you're trying to do.

Comment: Can you show the portion of the code where you assign a value to `kkcell` (i.e. `kkcell = ...;`)?  In the snippet you have there you are attempting to use it without assigning anything to it first.  That will crash pretty much always.

Comment: Not enough information here, but my first guess is that you never set the `AVAudioPlayer` delegate property to `nil`.  For backwards compatibility, the `AVAudioPlayer` delegate property is set to `assign` (*not* `weak`) so it needs to be manually set to `nil` if your object is deallocated before the `AVAudioPlayer` object is, or you will have a dangling pointer.

Comment: One trick you can do is define the dealloc method for your cell class. If you are using ARC, you don't have the [super dealloc]; call in your overloaded dealloc. This will let you see when your cell gets dealloc'd. You can also output info in the dealloc which identifies which cell, which can be helpful. BTW if your test for nil on kkcell is not preventing the problems, odds are your reference is dangling.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your project to ARC. It is much easier and automated than you would think. I've converted about 3 real life projects that were quite large in mid-development and never had any issues (put aside one hour to do it, you probably won't need that much time and its definitely worth it)

in Xcode, select
edit->refactor->convert to Objective-C ARC

You can also find tutorials online but its pretty straight forward overall.

Answer (score 0):

Your program crashes most likely because the object was indeed fully released but that doesn't mean that `kkcell` would be set to `nil`, hence your checks failing, `kkcell` is "dangling".

To answer your specific question, one way to test for release is to override `dealloc` as in

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"deallocated");
    [super dealloc];
}
```

This may help you troubleshoot by telling you exactly when the final release happens.